# question from logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Simplify without using tables          $$\frac{\log25+\log625}{\log5}$$

Comment: write 25 and 625 as powers of 5

Comment: Remember that $\log 5 = ?$ is the same as $10^{?}=5$

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{\log25}{\log5}+\frac{\log625}{\log5}=\frac{\log5^2}{\log5}+\frac{\log5^4}{\log5}=\frac{2\log5}{\log5}+\frac{4\log5}{\log5}=2+4=6 $$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\log_b a^n = n \log_b a $, $\log a + \log b = \log ab$

Rewrite in terms of powers of 5:

$$\frac{ \log 5^2 + \log 5^4}{\log 5}= \frac{\log (5^2 \times 5^4)}{\log 5} = \frac{6\log 5}{\log 5} = ?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\log25+\log625}{\log5}=\frac{\log(5^2*5^4)}{\log5}=6$$